# Spring как получить ответ от controller

Tags: json, spring, controller

я новичок, и у меня есть глупый вопрос: Я шлю запрос на Vk api и получаю в ответ json через постман, как мне получить ответ с контроллера spring? Собственно это реализуется через EntiryResponse, Model или как?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Читать про java HttpClient. Spring тут вообще не причем. Вообще у спринга есть RestTemplate, при помощи которого можно по-выполнять HTTP-запросы. Но Вам бы матчасть подучить про HTTP в принципе, и про Spring в частности.

Comment: Спасибо, HttpClient я как раз таки использую, я просто неправильно понимал предназначение контроллеров, а RestTemplate мне будет очень полезен.